# Breaking (\par) environment inside of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'd like to add a transparent box over an image and add some text, three names, one below the other. The approach I'm following give me the transparent box the way I want, but I'm not able to get the names one below the other. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[preaction={fill=white,fill, opacity=.6},rounded
        corners=1ex,font=\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\scshape] 
        {{Some text A} \par {Some text B} \par {Some text C}\par};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `\begin{tikzpicture}` in your document. ;-)

Leaving that aside, if you wish to force linebreaks inside a `TikZ` node, one of the ways to do this is to use the `align` option in the node (described in 17.4.3 in `pgfman.pdf`, p.223ff) and force linebreaks via `\\` (there may be other ways, but that's the approach with which I am familiar).

Does this produce the desired result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[
        preaction={fill=white,
        fill,
        opacity=.6},
        rounded corners=1ex,
        align=left,
        font=\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\scshape
    ] 
        {Some text A \\ Some text B \\ Some text C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are other options for `align` besides `left` (although `left` is probably what you'd want here):

- `flush left`
- `right`
- `flush right`
- `center`
- `flush center`
- `justify`

Also of interest might be the `text width` option (not necessarily for this example, just in general for handling text in `TikZ` nodes). It's described in the same section of the PGF manual. For explanations of the options and a visual demonstration of their effects, a look at the manual is probably the easiest way.

The PGF manual can be found here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf